# Scope of prototype function applying to wrong elements

Tags: javascript, this

Hi I have a class named `editor` and I have a function called like this:

```
Editor.prototype.switchTab = function(e) {
   var self = this;
   console.log(self);
}
```

I then add an event listener to an element like this in another prototype function.

```
Editor.prototype.foo = function() {
    var self = this;
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.addEventListener('click', self.switchTab, false);
}
```

The problem is that in the switchTab function, `this` refers to the `element`, not the `Editor` class. How can I fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with variable scope.

Comment: You should do `var f = self.switchTab.bind(self); element.addEventListener('click',f,false)`